# I want to copy and run .exe file on a remote Windows machine?

Tags: c#, windows, remote-access

i have copied the exe file and it was no problem, useing the following code, but now i want to run it, can anyboyd help me on this. 
NOTE: i have the access to servers through remote desktop, but cant do this manually, coz there are dozens of them, cant get a program running on it like psex or whatever.

```
WindowsIdentity wi = new WindowsIdentity(token);

//Next I set the WindowsImportsonationContext

WindowsImpersonationContext impctx = wi.Impersonate();
System.IO.File.Copy("C:\\output.html", "\\\\PW42\\c$\\output1.html", true);
System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
try
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"\\PW42\c$\txt.bat");
    //runFile();
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("error");
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that be a major security hole?

Comment: @Marko it can be a security whole if i cant access the pc through remote desktop at all, but in my case i can do that, and i am the administrator of all the pcs so know the administrator username and password

Comment: What is token? How to get it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what access you have on the server you can use a program like [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) or using WMI to launch the file remotely.

A sample psexec command would be

```
psexec \\computername -u remoteusername filepath(on remote computer) arguments
```

Psexec can copy the file beforehand if requested and can run against a list of computers instead (replacing `\\computername` with `@computer-list.txt`). With WMI you need to connect to the `Win32_Process` class and Create a new object to start it. The [second post](http://www.devnewsgroups.net/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework/topic48757.aspx) in this thread could work.

Unfortunately both of these options require multiple firewall rules (like RPC and WMI) to be available from the running workstation. If your company only has RDP access enabled through the firewall, neither of these will probably work.

Comment: actually there are hundreds of servers so need to do this automatically through code, cant go there to install psexec thanks

Comment: psexec doesn't need to be installed, it takes care of that itself when run for the first time. If it can access the remote computer with admin credentials you can run psexec.